# All In One Version Control - Debian

Tags: debian, open-source, version-control

I'm currently setting up a SVN repro for personal use. Normally on Debian that'd be svnserve, trac, maybe Apache... and that's three apps to take care of. Most stuff requires an Apache, but I use a lighttpd.

I want one server app that does that. Is there something - like a trac wiki that brings its own SVN server?

wishi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't subversion but it is an all in one solution like you want. Look at [fossil](http://www.fossil-scm.org/index.html/doc/tip/www/index.wiki) I've had good luck using it for personal projects.

Answer (score 2):

Since trac will take care of code and revisions browsing, why not simply use the stand-alone tracserver? I won't be listening on port 80, but since it's your private repo it shouldn't hurt.
Additionally, you don't really need svnserver when you use svn over ssh. And I guess that ssh is already running on your box.

Comment: Even if *tracserver* doesn't listen on port 80, a redirect can be done:

`iptables -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports NNN`.

Answer (score 2):

I use Subversion for personal use and, in that case, SSH is all what is needed. My URL is:

```
svn+ssh://svn.example.org/home/stephane/Subversion-Personal-Repository
```

and this requires nothing on  `svn.example.org` except a SSH server which I already have.

Answer (score 0):

Even if something configures them all together, it's still three apps to take care of, and the attempted integration will just make it harder to figure out what goes wrong, when it inevitably does.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't mind keeping notes and stuff on the side, you can of course use git and omit the 'repository' concept altogether. and if you need to, you can serve it whenever. ...And scale up, if that'd happen.

Comment: git is interesting but it is not the question asked (and git has repositorieS).

Comment: I was hoping to solve the problem, rather than simply answering the question. With just a distributed vcs, there's no need to set up a service *until and unless* there's a better reason to. (I've made this mistake myself.)